# Passing function's output to variable in "if" statement

Tags: python

in PHP I'm used to do this to check if a function returns something other than `false` and pass the result to a variable

```
function my_function(){
      $return = "test"; 
      return $return

}

if ($output = my_function()){
     echo $output;
}
```

How do I do the same in Python without having to call "my_function" twice?

Comment: This is not a PHP to Python conversion service.

Comment: [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: Don't you need to do `my_function()`, with the parenthesis, in order to call a funcion in PHP?

Comment: Just do the variable assignment before the if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
def my_function():
    return "test"

output = my_function()
if output:
    print(output)
```

Comment: thanks haven't thought about this simple step, anyway since when stackoverflow became full of mean people ready to offend you the moment you post something? God.

Comment: @SandroAntonucci you didn't talk about parties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558770/php-equivalent-of-pythons-textwrap-dedent :( Seems that's a requirement from conceptualizing something in another language